# php image loading time consumption

Tags: php

I have a products website where in I have around 100 images of high quality. Each image is around 6-7MB in size.

In my database I have stored the path of all the images along with their names. The images are saved in a folder /images/product_name/, But when I go to display these images in a web page, the page takes forever to load. All I do is send the id to the table, get the image paths and display it in the products page.

It would be very helpful if I could get any sort of advice on how to optimize the process.

Comment: You might have done something like reading every file, but it is hard to tell without source.

Comment: How long do you think loading 100 times 6 to 7 MB images should take?  How long is it taking?

Comment: Speed can be any number of variables. Do you have a publicly accessible version that I can run debug tools? You have close to 1GB of images on that page, these will always take a long time to load.

Comment: You can resize the image using PHP to reduce its size (width/height), not sure if you have only option to display full image, if so you should make it something like preload, also images should be optimized for web.

Comment: no..no reading of files come into play...it is as simple as this..get the path of the images with a select query..and with those paths..get the images from the respective folder..

Comment: It's hard to optimize a process which we can't see. Post some code

Comment: @wallyk - The product gallery page takes forever...keeps loading one by one but doesn stop at all..want to know if there is anything such as taking a thumbnail of these images and then displaying them?

Comment: @MLeFevre just the retrieving part in my view file

<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>cuff_images/<?php echo $image_name[$i]->cuff_name; ?>" alt="gallery-image" class="on"/>
<div class="<?php echo $class; ?>" id="k<?php echo $cnt; ?>" onclick="javascript:get_data('<?php echo $image_name[$i]->id;?>','k<?php echo $cnt; ?>');"></div>
</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/ to compress images.
It is one of the simple and free tools recommended by Google to compress images.

Also as it was mentioned before make sure the thumbs you send to the listing pages are around 100px and only if the user clicks to zoom in show him the large ones one by one, and still even in the zoom option you should only display a 1000px size image max and that should not have more then 200-500k depending on format and quality.

Answer (score 6):

The images you send to the client are most likely way too big. 7MB of size sounds very large for a product picture so 100*7MB = 700MB of data transfered if you display all the product images.

If you only need small images, scale them down to some KB's (thumbnails) and use those to display in your table.

NOTE: you can just preprend a prefix like "tmb_" or "tmb_200x200_" to the original filename, and you won't have to touch the paths in the database.

Answer (score 1):

From reading your comments I think you are looking for some automated process to optimize the files and serve them at a more decent filesize.

You should take a look at [imageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) which allows you to resize images (among many other things - http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) and optimize them. This can be combined with something like the [YUI Image cropper](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/imagecropper/adv_crop.html) to allow you to choose certain parts of the image to show in the thumbnail.

This is best done at the point of upload so the Server doesn't unnecessarily regenerate the images each time they are requested, and stored under a thumbnail column in the database.

If you must show bigger images I suggest you use a [lightbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_%28JavaScript%29) (see an example here - http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) or similar technique that only loads the larger image when the client requests it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have optimized your images (in term of file size) ? Like on Smush.it for example http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/

Comment: No i havent optimized my images because i want them to be the same (lookswise) ,cant really afford to reduce the sharpness of the products.

Comment: You'll be forced to optimize the file size... It's totally normal that it takes time to load these images (regarding their sizes)

Comment: This helped a lot...page load time has reduced by 40% atleast..thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should really optimize your images. You can use a commercial product like Photoshop or use a free one like the GIMP to optimize the files.
Loading about 700 MBs of images will take exactly 1 day for me!!

Answer (score 0):

reduce the size of the images to a thumbnail and when the user clicks on the thumbnail then load the original file. This can increase the performance.